# Refer the keys of one enum to keys or values of another enum

Tags: typescript, enums

In below code, Keys of `PropertiesNamesInDataBase` must be even with `User.Keys`.
The values of `PropertiesNamesInDataBase`, as is obviously from name, are being using in backend, but names in frontend must be unified.

```js
namespace User {
    export enum Keys {
        ID = "ID",
        name = "name"
    }
}

enum PropertiesNamesInDataBase {
    ID = "id",
    name = "nm"
}
```

At least two problems here:

1. We need to re-type keys or copy-paste them
2. `PropertiesNamesInDataBase` is fully independent on `User.Keys`, however conceptually `PropertiesNamesInDataBase`'s keys must refer to `User.Keys` by some way.

Here is attempt to solve the second problem by referencing of `PropertiesNamesInDataBase` keys to `User.Keys`:

```js
namespace User {
    export enum Keys {
        ID = "ID",
        name = "name"
    }
}

enum PropertiesNamesInDataBase {
    [User.Keys.ID] = "id",
    [User.Keys.name] = "nm"
}
```

However it's impossible in TypeScript:

```
Computed property names are not allowed in enums. (1164)
```

Please ever tech me how to reuse enum keys, or how to refer `PropertiesNamesInDataBase`'s keys on `User.Keys`'s values.

Comment: Do you *need* `enum`s specifically, or would [other data structures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBA0gUwJ4QIJgCYAUBOIAOAcgIYC2CEMAvDAN4CwAUDDAJIAiAXHTANbLcARB0EAaGPjxEyCIQEsMgmAF9RTFmBndafATEGbyYiVJLkhYUkuVNlMYpVCQoAbiZMn0GAFUICHNQ8iCjcIABGAFYAssT4uAQAFMFomPHS5BDigvxIggCUKm6MnrBp-lByFGYUrGDsxFDEAEIOCIHh0bFpScgp2KYymfqSBNX5RUwA9JMwADZyYTjEOEhMAGYArmDAFeAwHTFxUgA8ACowCAAeUAiYlABKCKA4GMc5IGswp+KPz69w4mIYCQAD4QeI4BdrrcMJR3p8gaCEup9pFuN8UTluHAmAUGMwYCUYDgELAaLQ7A4eABtLAwORgXRID5fAC66NprOpcFZhRRaxAAQSs1JfHpjI6eJRLBJUGpvF5NA68q5OVZRRYNgJso2OEZsqKWqAA) work?

Comment: @jcalz, other data structures is O'K.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be inclined to forget about `enum` entirely and instead build up your own enum-like objects.  This will give you the flexibility you need to write the keys only once, but you will lose some of the built-in expressiveness that comes with `enum` (namely that `enum Foo {...}` creates both an *object* named `Foo` and a *type* named `Foo`.  If you create `const Foo = ...` instead, you only get the *object*, and will need to define your own type yourself if you want it).

Here's one approach:

```
const KeysAndPropNames = {
  ID: { key: "ID", propName: "id" },
  name: { key: "name", propName: "nm" }
} as const;
```

You've got just one object which is a mapping from key to the values you had in your old `User.Keys` and `PropertiesNamesInDataBase` enums.  You can extract those enum-like objects yourself like this:

```
const User = { Keys: objMapProp(KeysAndPropNames, "key") };
const PropertiesNamesInDataBase = objMapProp(KeysAndPropNames, "propName");
```

where `objMapProp()` is a function you can put in a library that maps a property access over an object:

```
// library
function objMapProp<T extends Record<keyof T, Record<K, any>>, K extends keyof any>(
  obj: T,
  key: K
) {
  const ret = {} as { [P in keyof T]: T[P][K] };
  for (let k in obj) {
    ret[k] = obj[k][key];
  }
  return ret;
}
```

If you examine the type of the new `User` and `PropertiesNamesInDataBase` objects with IntelliSense, you'll see they match up to the old values:

```
/* const User: {
    Keys: {
        readonly ID: "ID";
        readonly name: "name";
    };
} */

/* const PropertiesNamesInDataBase: {
    readonly ID: "id";
    readonly name: "nm";
} */
```

If you want the *types* named `User.Keys` and `PropertiesNamesInDataBase`, you can make them as the union of all the value types of the corresponding objects:

```
namespace User {
  export type Keys = (typeof User.Keys)[keyof typeof User.Keys];
  // type User.Keys = "ID" | "name"
}
type PropertiesNamesInDataBase = typeof PropertiesNamesInDataBase[keyof typeof PropertiesNamesInDataBase];
// type PropertiesNamesInDataBase = "id" | "nm"
```

---

Anyway, hope that either meets your needs or gives you some idea how to proceed.  Good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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-24OJiGAkAA+GfiOAt2ltju6JBSqezhJ1G7cYd1HLcOBMArUliVGAdWA0Wh2Bw8MVYGByMBrqWNxV7x+KsVwRWFOpeUZGAEh6BBYF4Z9XxuU9WkvcCJX-GgbkQv0kEjGEbBhK8SxwV8r2WJggA)